# JPA Query not returning data while sending multiple values in request

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having issue finding null or empty list in my JPA Query. I was able to get the values for single and empty value selection via request. But, same this is not working if I pass multiple values.

```
@Query(
      value =
          "select sum (ORDER_PALLET_QTY) as PALLETS, 
              sum (ORDER_QTY) as UNITS, 
              PO_TYPE as POTYPE 
              from [ORDER]
              where CAL_DT BETWEEN (:fromDate) AND (:endDate) AND 
              (:vendor IS NULL OR VENDOR_NBR IN (:vendor)) AND 
              group by PO_TYPE,
      nativeQuery = true)
  Optional<List<OrderCubeModelHelper>> getOrders(
      List<String> vendorNbr,
      LocalDate fromDate,
      LocalDate endDate);
```

This is returning data when I send only one value in list. As shown below:

Request:

```
{
  "vendorNbr" :["294"],
  "fromDate" : "2021-08-12",
  "endDate" : "2021-08-31"
}
```

Same query throwing exception when I send multiple values in request.

SampleRequest

```
   {
      "vendorNbr" :["294","302"],
      "fromDate" : "2021-08-12",
      "endDate" : "2021-08-31"
    }
```

Exception:

```
2021-08-19 11:46:18.520 ERROR 12404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a native query, and AFAIK Hibernate does not interfere in any way to do parameter list expansion as it is generally hard to support all SQL dialects through a single parser. If you want list expansion to happen, you either have to use some kind of table valued function e.g. [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or you use JPQL/HQL for this query like this:

```
@Query("select new package.to.OrderCubeModelHelper(sum(e.palletQuantity), sum (e.quantity), e.poType) from OrderEntity e
          where e.date BETWEEN (:fromDate) AND (:endDate) AND 
          (:vendor IS NULL OR e.vendorNumber IN (:vendor)) AND 
          group by e.poType")
Optional<List<OrderCubeModelHelper>> getOrders(
  List<String> vendorNbr,
  LocalDate fromDate,
  LocalDate endDate);
```

Comment: Actually, I solved this problem using JPA `criteria builder`. I will try to make use of this example and see if it works.